# Latest stable version of Flink on K8s

Tags: apache-flink

I have Flink 1.12 and I am using Yarn cluster for deployment. I want to move to K8s but first I would like to upgrade to the latest version of Flink that is stable on K8s. What is the latest Flink version that is stable on K8s?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the latest stable release of Flink ***should*** be running stable on K8s. ([Flink documentation for 1.14](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/resource-providers/native_kubernetes/))

From personal experience I can verify that version 1.13.2 is running stable.
I however did not test 1.14 yet, but plan to do soon.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I upgraded to 1.14 and deployed it in Yarn. Everything is running smoothly. Now I am planning to deploy it  on K8s.